# Outlook meeting requests - participants' responses

Tags: calendar, microsoft-outlook-2013

When sending meeting requests from a colleague's Outlook account on which I have been granted access, how do I avoid responses being sent to this colleague but to my own email address instead?

The objective is to avoid "polluting" the inbox of my colleague with information that he does not need. I know that this is feasible for emails, but cannot find the option for calendar entries.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to create the meeting using the colleague's account and invite only yourself. You can then forward that meeting invitation to any other participants.